# Time field in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am trying to create simple time field in my Java Play Framework application. I've prepared a class:

```
public class Schedule extends AbstractEntity {

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
public Date arrival;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    public Date departure;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Variant variant;

}
```

I try to obtain some departure and arrival times via this template:

```
 <div class="modal-body">
                @helper.form(action = routes.TripTimesController.addSchedule(trip)) {
                    @helper.inputText(scheduleForm("arrival"), '_label -> "Arrival", '_type ->"time")

                    @helper.inputText(scheduleForm("departure"), '_label -> "Destination", '_type ->"time" )

                    <select name="variant">
                    @for(variant <- Variant.values()){
                        <option value="@variant.name()">@variant.name()</option>
                    }
                    </select>

                </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
            }
```

No matter what I type, I cannot pass the validation, and I always get the information that the form has errors:

```
 Form<Schedule> form = Form.form(Schedule.class).bindFromRequest();
        if(form.hasErrors()) {
            ...
        }
```

What is the correct format of time in Play? Are there any Time helper that could be useful for forcing the correct formatting?

Comment: Have you tried to see what are the errors ? Make sure to import `java.util.Date` and what is the aim of your `@Temporal` annotations ?

Comment: With @Temporal, I was trying to force time formatting of the date (for TIME column in MySQL database), like this cheat sheet suggested https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.x/cheatsheet/model. There are no errors when I enter null values, but whatever else I try to type  I end up with invalid form.

Comment: This cheatsheet is for Play 1.2.x. Play 2.X is completely different from the first version. If you want to validate your date, see `@play.data.format.Formats.DateTime(pattern = "THE_PATTERN_THAT_YOU_WANT")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bindFromRequest` is expecting `yyyy-MM-dd` representation. To add a the marshalling of a custom representaiton (long conversion or "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS") you have to use a custom DataBinder.

Some months ago I opened a [ticket about a similar issue on GitHub](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3097#issuecomment-47441276) for it, where in the end I posted my binding.

However, and as pointed out already, if you want to support an specific Date format from [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you may just use the annotation: `@play.data.format.Formats.DateTime`.

So in your case, only for a time is "HH:mm:ss": `@Formats.DateTime(pattern = "HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: And what is the expected representation when all I want is only the time, not the date?

Comment: Your object is a type `Date` and play marshalls Date types with `yyyy-MM-dd` by default. Did you tried adding the  @Formats.DateTime with your corresponding [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) expression?

Comment: yep,  @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "HH:mm:ss") works flawlessy. Please update an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I updated my answer with the corresponding dateformat for time.